# GridGain: How to add composite primary keys

Tags: gridgain

In GridGain, I have to load data such that the primary key is a composite key.

Say I have

```
class Person{
    int id;
    int officeId;
    ...
}
```

Here I want to add as primary key both id and officeId. Is it possible to add a composite key in GridGain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in GridGain any Object can be used as a key, just like with HashMaps. You need to make sure that you override `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` methods for the composite keys.

Comment: It should not affect performance. To speed up serialization you should also have it implement java.io.Externalizable interface (the same goes for cache values).